# Связываем 2 selecta через js

Tags: javascript, html

Вообщем у меня есть 2 select`а и у каждого из них есть on change, так вот мне надо когда я передал данные из одного select в другой, этот on change запустить это возможно? Вот мой код который передаёт данные:

```
$(".select_razmer").on('change', function () {
    var money = this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-money'].value;
    var default_price = this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-price'].value;
    var product_id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-id_product'].value;
    $('#product_popup_' + product_id + ' .popup-body .popup-product__content .popup-product__content_text .cart-list__item-razmer .select_razmer_main').val($(this).val());
    var new_money = 0;
    console.log(money);
    console.log(default_price);
    if (money > 0) {
        new_money = parseInt(default_price) + parseInt(money);
        console.log('Плюс ' + new_money);
        $(this).parent().next().children('.row').children('.price_product_one').html(number_format(new_money, 2, ',', ' ') + ' руб.');
    } else {
        new_money = parseInt(default_price) + parseInt(money);
        console.log('Минус ' + new_money);
        $(this).parent().next().children('.row').children('.price_product_one').html(number_format(new_money, 2, ',', ' ') + ' руб.');
    }
});

$(".select_razmer_main").on('change', function () {
    var money = this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-money'].value;
    var default_price = this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-price'].value;
    var product_id = this.options[this.selectedIndex].attributes['data-id_product'].value;
    var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        if (elements[i].getAttribute('data-key') === product_id) {
            var tr_elem = elements[i];
        }
    }
    $(tr_elem).children([3]).children(".select_razmer").val($(this).val());
    var new_money = 0;
    console.log(money);
    console.log(default_price);
    if (money > 0) {
        new_money = parseInt(default_price) + parseInt(money);
        console.log('Плюс ' + new_money);
        $(this).parent().next().children('.row').children('.price_product_one').html(number_format(new_money, 2, ',', ' ') + ' руб.');
    } else {
        new_money = parseInt(default_price) + parseInt(money);
        console.log('Минус ' + new_money);
        $(this).parent().next().children('.row').children('.price_product_one').html(number_format(new_money, 2, ',', ' ') + ' руб.');
    }
});
```

Ну думаю суть понятна.

Comment: $('.select_razmer') .val().trigger('change');

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы не боитесь зациклить два Ваши обработчика? Может быть не вызывать `change`, если значение не изменяется?

```
var otherSelect = $('#product_popup_' + product_id + ' .popup-body .popup-product__content .popup-product__content_text .cart-list__item-razmer .select_razmer_main');
if (otherSelect.val() != $(this).val());
  otherSelect.val($(this).val()).change();


var otherSelect = $(tr_elem).children([3]).children(".select_razmer");
if (otherSelect.val() != $(this).val());
  otherSelect.val($(this).val()).change();
```

---

Кхм, кхм. Не

```
var elements = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
    if (elements[i].getAttribute('data-key') === product_id) {
        var tr_elem = elements[i];
    }
}
```

a

```
var tr_elem = $("tr[data-key='" + product_id + "'");
```

Comment: Ну да, про зацикливания я как-то не особо задумывался.